# Navigation bar button not showing with tinted color iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am having view controllers 
And I am showing like this
Let assume 1,2,3 are the view controllers.
I navigate like this
1->2->3

When I come back
3->2->1
then from 1 the navigation bar button item cancel of UIImagePicker doesn't show. If I don't go with this sequence (1->2->3
) It shows perfectly.
Please let me know what could be the issue.

I am using opaque navigation bar.

And the navigation bar tint and bar tint color I am updating like this in the appdelegate class

```
 func setNavigationAppearance(tintColor : UIColor, barTintColor : UIColor?) {

        let navigationBarAppearace = appDelegateObj.navigationController!.navigationBar

        navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = tintColor

        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = tintColor

        navigationBarAppearace.translucent = false

        //navigationBarAppearace.

        //Settign the Custome Font and TextColor

        if let font = UIFont(name: FontCustom.Regular, size: 17) {

            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font ,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : tintColor]
        }

    }
```

And adding the background image to the navigation bar like this

```
 if let myImage = UIImage(named: AppImagesName.PatternRed) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(myImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        }
```

Comment: Before this I was working with these view controller by presenting.
But issue was the same

Comment: You have written swift code, but you tagged for swift and Objective C?

Comment: @Janmenjaya,I did because I want to know the solution. Any one can provide the answer. If user knows Objective-C or swift.

Comment: One thing to clarify, are you able to see the bar button in screen 1. Because you have set the barTint color and tint color as same.barTintColor is for responsible for navigation bar's background color, where as tintColor is for the back round color of bar button on navigation bar. So if it would be of same color then i suppose you can't see the button!! But How could you find it invisible only in case of coming back to the screen?

Comment: Ok I will try to check it with after updating it.

Comment: @Janmenjaya, I have tried but it is not working

Comment: I had a similar issue with my project.I did a different approach and it worked for me.I was playing with navigationBar settings and programmatically created a navBar and statusBar using UIView) and  I connected 3 VC without using any  segue..i suggest you to update navigationBar setting on each VC that could solve your problem...